# Asp.net core How to bind data and get value of select TagHelper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

Before everything look at my Model.

**SystemPart Model**

```
public class systemPart
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string systemName { get; set; }
   public int systemLevel { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use this model in `Create` view. also In `create` view i want to have a `<select>` TagHelper from the same Model.

Look at `Create` View

```
@model MyProject.Models.systemPart
<form asp-controller="SystemPart" asp-action="Create" method="post">


        <div class="form-group">
            <input asp-for="systemName" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <select asp-for="systemName" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.SysList,"id","systemName"))"  class="form-control"></select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>

    </form>
```

And in Controller I have :

```
   public class RoleController : Controller
   {
      private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
      public RoleController(ApplicationDbContext context)
      {
        _context = context;
      }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var sp = new List<systemPart>();
        sp = _context.sysPart_Tbl.ToList();
        ViewBag.SysList = sp;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(systemPart model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //
        }
        return View(model);
    }
   }
```

Now after lunch project `DropDownList` display info. But after select an option in `DropDownList` and submit form i cant get selected text and id.

At `HttpPost` action method, I want the amount of the selected value (selected `id`) assign to `SystemLevel`

Comment: A `<select>` posts the value of its selected option, not the selected text. And you already have an input for `systemName` before the dropdownlist, and its the value of that input that will be bound to your model (the value of the `<select>` will be ignored)

Comment: @StephenMuecke How can i do to solve it?

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to solve (your code is not making sense). If you want to bind the value of the selected option to `systemName"`, then remove the first input. But you do not have a input for `systemLevel` so I am not sure if that is what you want to bind the dropdownlist to

Comment: For current code, what is your expected value for `systemPart model`? Do you want to get `systemLevel` by `select tag` from `ViewBag.SysList` based on `Id` value? If you want `model.systemLevel` value from `systemPart.id` in `Create(systemPart model)`, try `<select asp-for="systemLevel" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.SysList,"id","systemName"))" `.

Comment: Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-2.0 It will help you understanding what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change asp-for="systemName" to asp-for="SystemLevel"!

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <select asp-for="SystemLevel" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.SysList,"id","systemName"))"  class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
```